# How add Check Constraints migration Codeigniter PostgreSQL

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I'm trying to do the following migration table below:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE 
(
    product_no integer,
    name text,
    price numeric positive_price CHECK (price> 0) 
);
```

PHP:

```
$this->dbforge->drop_table('products', true);
$this->dbforge->add_field(array(
   'product_no' => array(
      'type' => 'INTEGER'
    ),
   'name' => array(
      'type' => 'VARCHAR',
      'constraint' => '20'
    ),
   'price' => array(
      'type' => 'NUMERIC',
      'constraint' => 'CONSTRAINT positive_price CHECK (price > 0)'
   )
));
$this->dbforge->add_key('product_no', TRUE);
$this->dbforge->create_table('products');
```

But the generated query is not valid:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "products" ( "product_no" INTEGER NOT NULL, "name" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "price" NUMERIC(positive_price CHECK (price > 0)) NOT NULL )
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time thinking about the solution found. To generate the table equal to the example using 'migrations' was enough to add the 'CHECK (price> 0)' after finishing the course.

PHP:

```
'price' => array(
   'type' => 'NUMERIC CHECK (price > 0)'
)
```